# How can we compare value of two different rows but in same table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need something like this.

[image]

here Remarks is based on if one student fails in at least one subject then  remarks should be "Fail" otherwise if the student passes all subjects then 'Pass']
Please Help

```
Select StudentID,Case when Marks>= PassMarks then 'Pass' end as Re 
from tbl_ExamResult 
group by StudentID,Marks,PassMarks
```

Comment: Can you clarify: if they **fail** everything ("all subject"), you want it to say _Pass_? That seems backwards. Seems like if they fail **anything**, it should say "Fail".

Comment: Also: posting images of technical information like sample data, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. You'll be more likely to get help if you **edit the question** to change the image to use [table formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post)

Comment: You can use an `apply` operator to check for any non pass value. If there are non-pass values, evaluate it to Fail, otherwise pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select StudentID,Marks,PassMarks
      ,ISNULL(MAX(Case when Marks < PassMarks THEN 'Fail' END), 'Pass')
from tbl_ExamResult 
group by StudentID,Marks,PassMarks
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ko3B26du

```
declare @tbl_ExamResult table (
  StudentId int not null
, Name varchar(100) not null
, SubjectWiseResult char(4) not null
);
insert @tbl_ExamResult (StudentId, Name, SubjectWiseResult)
values (1,'A','Pass')
     , (1,'A','Fail')
     , (1,'A','Pass')
     , (2,'B','Pass')
     , (2,'B','Pass');

select StudentId
     , Name
     , SubjectWiseResult
     , case
          when itvf.NonPass = 0 then 'Pass'
          else 'Fail'
       end as Remarks
  from @tbl_ExamResult tbl_ExamResult
cross apply (
             select count(*) as NonPass
               from @tbl_ExamResult insideTable
              where insideTable.StudentId = tbl_ExamResult.StudentId
                and SubjectWiseResult <> 'Pass'
            ) itvf;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowed count over a conditional value for this. There is no need to use `GROUP BY`

```sql
SELECT
  e.StudentID,
  e.Name,
  e.Subject,
  e.PassMarks,
  e.Marks,
  v.SubjectWiseResult,
  CASE WHEN
    COUNT(v.SubjectWiseResult) OVER (PARTITION BY Student) = 0
    THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END AS Remarks
FROM tbl_ExamResult e
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
      CASE WHEN Marks < PassMarks THEN 1 END
) ) v(SubjectWiseResult);
```